# How do I find oldest unanswered question

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, old-posts

I like being a "necromancer" in CV and digging through the bones of things that have been abandoned but are meaningful.

I want to search unanswered, as in zero answers at all, questions by my tag, ordered from oldest to newest.

How do I do that.  I saw that the interface had a "newest" option, but not an "oldest" option.

Comment: Is there any problem skipping to the last page when ordered by "newest" and working back from that?

Comment: You can use the advanced search options to set a date range.

Comment: +1 I like being a necromancer also. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can you use the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to write an SQL query that does exactly what you want. Below a query that returns what you are looking for. That is, unanswered posts, sorted from oldest to newest, that are not closed and contain the tags you will define in the parenthenses in the `t.TagName IN ('r', 'monte-carlo')` clause (I used 'r' and 'monte-carlo' just for example).

```
select distinct p.Id AS [Post Link], p.*
from Posts p
  inner join PostHistory ph on ph.postid = p.id
  join PostTags pt ON pt.PostId = p.Id
  join Tags t  ON t.Id = pt.TagId
where p.PostTypeId = 1 and p.AnswerCount = 0 and ph.PostHistoryTypeId != 10 -- closed
and t.TagName IN ('r', 'monte-carlo')
order by p.CreationDate asc
```

Note that the site queried is not part of the query itself. You have to select it in the query configuration page by searching for the site you want.

You can use the above query already configured for the Cross Validated site [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/1402777/oldest-unanswered-questions-in-cross-validated-filtered-by-tags-and-sorted-oldes) (allow it some seconds and it will probably execute automatically; if not just click "Run Query"). You may fork it and edit it as you like.

If you want to learn more about writing queries against the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, have a look into their [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

As a comment to the answer by @gung, some more examples of the advanced search features, modify, mix & match at will. The first is my standard starting point:

```
experiment-design answers:0 closed:no duplicate:no                (845 hits)
experiment-design answers:0 closed:no duplicate:no score:0        (249 hits)
experiment-design answers:0 closed:no duplicate:no views:..20     (171 hits)
experiment-design answers:0 closed:no duplicate:no created:..2012 (44 hits)
```

For more search operators, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/searching. Note that `..` is the **range operator**, which can be used with many search operators, as in `2015..2018` which is inclusive, so from 1 January 2015 to 31 December 2018, or `2021..` which is after (inclusive) 1 January 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Use the various [advanced search features](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/searching).  To find unanswered threads, search for `answers:0 closed:no`.  Then you can sort by `Newest`, and skip to the last page (currently [1074](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?page=1074&tab=Newest&q=answers%3a0%20closed%3ano)): the oldest non-closed question without answers appears to be [What's good about I-projections?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2079/whats-good-about-i-projections) posted on Aug 24, 2010.